# How to authenticate a Google Games player on a backend server

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

The docs, once again, just have me going in circles

The Games sign-in documentation suggests using normal Google sign in procedure:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin
which points to using *ID token* for server-side user authentication:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth
but, it seems, there isn't a way to obtain a *Games player ID* matching this verifiable ID token, which means in the end we can't establish authenticity of a Games player that did the sign-in.

I have also found a [verify](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/applications/verify) call that seem to be designed to obtain a Games player ID, but it is locked behind an *access token*, which would force additional permssions upon login, and a more complicated client-server exchange, and is undesirable in general, as we are not aiming to do any Google calls on users behalf.

It is bizarre that there isn't a direct way to check the Games id authenticity back with Google. Is there another authentication procedure for Games id, that I'm just missing maybe?

Answer (score 1):

> It is bizarre that there isn't a direct way to check the Games id authenticity back with Google. Is there another authentication procedure for Games id, that I'm just missing maybe?

There is, and you mentioned it in your question: use the access token.

Hook that up with the Google_Service_Games ang you get the same ID. (Begins g; the openID is numerical only)

```
        $googleClient = new \Google_Client();
        $googleClient->setClientId(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
        $googleClient->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
        $googleClient->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
        $googleClient->setScopes('googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');

        $googleToken = json_encode([
            'access_token' => $accessToken,
            'token_type' => '',
            'expires_in' => 1800,
            'id_token' => '',
            'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
            'created' => time()
        ]);
        $googleClient->setAccessToken($googleToken);

        $gamesService = new \Google_Service_Games($googleClient);
        $me = $gamesService->players->get('me');
        $me = $me->toSimpleObject();
```

Comment: That is a possibility; the problem is it does not follow the rest of the auth logic, and looks like a hack hurting the user safety. It should not be necessary to request account access when all I need is Google to confirm the authenticity of a token. It isn't for a Google account, so shouldn't be for a Games identity accessed with it.

Comment: In which case, go the OpenID route: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect - this gives you a JWT token that is signed by google and that you can verify. I don't have a code sample as we've only recently looked at that approach - but it's how we verify AppleIDs so I assme there will be a sample somewhere.

Comment: Update - there's actually an example on that page: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery

Comment: The android/backend-auth procedure above produces a similar verifiable token as well; it seem to just be a platform-specialised variant of this same OAuth authentification.  But I am finding no way to reliably match that token back to a Games player ID.

Comment: I don't think platform specific (It's actually a standard and you do the same to verify apple login).  If you just want to check the id is a one with a use behind it, use this method.

Game.Players.loadPlayer(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String playerId)

Comment: Doing that in the app won't achieve much. We have got the id, but it is sent to a backend server and then there is no way to know if it came from our app, or from a hacker pretending to be another player. That's where we need it to be authenticated.

Comment: Where did you get Client Id and Client Secret for your server?

Comment: @gherman In the google api console, check the "credentials" section.